# Polynomials Linked List Test Case for adding no errors not doing anything

Tags: c, list, polynomials

This part of our code is meant to create two polynomials which are then to be added. The Main tests that this is done successfully. When I build there are no errors but nothing happens on run time. I am not sure why this happens we have been stuck for quite a while. When the createPoly functions are commented out it seems to run and print blank polynomials so we are not sure what is wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct link{
       int coeff;
       int pow;
       struct link *next;
       };
struct link *poly1=NULL,*poly2=NULL,*poly=NULL, *polyAddC=NULL;

void createPoly1(struct link *node)
{
    node->coeff = 3;
    node->pow = 0;
    node=node->next;
    node->next=NULL;
    node->coeff = 4;
    node->pow = 1;
    node=node->next;
    node->next=NULL;
    node->coeff = 6;
    node->pow = 2;
    node=node->next;
    node->next=NULL;
    node->coeff = 7;
    node->pow = 3;
}

void createPoly2(struct link *node)
{
    node->coeff = 4;
    node->pow = 0;
    node=node->next;
    node->next=NULL;
    node->coeff = 5;
    node->pow = 1;
    node=node->next;
    node->next=NULL;
    node->coeff = 1;
    node->pow = 2;
    node=node->next;
    node->next=NULL;
    node->coeff = 3;
    node->pow = 3;
}

void createPolyAddCorrect(struct link *node)
{
    node->coeff = 7;
    node->pow = 0;
    node=node->next;
    node->next=NULL;
    node->coeff = 9;
    node->pow = 1;
    node=node->next;
    node->next=NULL;
    node->coeff = 7;
    node->pow = 2;
    node=node->next;
    node->next=NULL;
    node->coeff = 10;
    node->pow = 3;
}

void displayPoly(struct link *node)
{
 while(node->next!=NULL)
 {
  printf("%dx^%d",node->coeff,node->pow);
  node=node->next;
  if(node->next!=NULL)
   printf("+");
 }
}
void addPoly(struct link *poly1,struct link *poly2,struct link *poly)
{
     while(poly1->next &&  poly2->next)
     {
      if(poly1->pow>poly2->pow)
      {
       poly->pow=poly1->pow;
       poly->coeff=poly1->coeff;
       poly1=poly1->next;
       }
      else if(poly1->pow<poly2->pow)
      {
       poly->pow=poly2->pow;
       poly->coeff=poly2->coeff;
       poly2=poly2->next;
       }
      else
      {
       poly->pow=poly1->pow;
       poly->coeff=poly1->coeff+poly2->coeff;
       poly1=poly1->next;
       poly2=poly2->next;
       }
      poly->next=(struct link *)malloc(sizeof(struct link));
      poly=poly->next;
      poly->next=NULL;
     }
     while(poly1->next || poly2->next)
     {
      if(poly1->next)
      {
       poly->pow=poly1->pow;
       poly->coeff=poly1->coeff;
       poly1=poly1->next;
       }
      if(poly2->next)
      {
       poly->pow=poly2->pow;
       poly->coeff=poly2->coeff;
       poly2=poly2->next;
       }
       poly->next=(struct link *)malloc(sizeof(struct link));
       poly=poly->next;
       poly->next=NULL;
       }
}
int main()
{
      poly1=(struct link *)malloc(sizeof(struct link));
      poly2=(struct link *)malloc(sizeof(struct link));
      poly=(struct link *)malloc(sizeof(struct link));
      polyAddC=(struct link *)malloc(sizeof(struct link));


    createPoly1(poly1);
    printf("\nFirst Polynomial: ");
    displayPoly(poly1);

    createPoly2(poly2);
    printf("\nSecond Polynomial: ");
    displayPoly(poly2);

    addPoly(poly1, poly2, poly);
    printf("\nAdded Polynomials: ");
    displayPoly(poly);

    createPolyAddCorrect(polyAddC);
    printf("\nCorrect Answer: ");
    displayPoly(polyAddC);
    if(poly==polyAddC)
    {
        printf("Test Passed");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Test Failed");
    }
}
` ` `
```

Comment: In your createPoly function, you are not initializing the second node, as in for the second node, with coeff=5, there is no block of memory allocated for it. Also from there on when you do node->next, you're pointing to a NULLptr and assigning values to it, The compiler should ideally throw an error here, don't know why it doesn't. Ideally for a second node, you should do node->next = (struct link *) malloc(sizeof(struct link)) before assigning values to it.

Comment: You need to review all your memory management.  You should aim to have a single polynomial create function that can be passed an array of terms, coefficient and power, and turn that into a linked list.  Then you’ll can enforce the correct sequence of increasing powers, and can deal with any holes (where one term is for power N and the next is for N+2 or larger) and so on.  You’ll need a function to free a polynomial too.

Comment: Before you start testing, better do a code review by peers.

Comment: Sorry, we figured it out a little bit after posting. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please delete this question if you’ve resolved the issues.